# Can't submit my Adobe Air app to Apple : Error ITMS-9000 - Minumum OS Version not supported?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

Hey all I've been trying to submit my Adobe Air app for the past few days with no success.  Below are the errors the Application Loader is giving me.  Note: I also tried to add the MinimumOSVersion to the application descriptor file, but it didnt seem to change anything.

ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle {appname}.app does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist."

WARNING ITMS-9000: "The executable 'Payload/{appname}.app' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more information refer to Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable in the iOS Developer Library."

I am using the most recent version of the Air SDK and tried with some of the other ones with no luck as well.  Anyone have an insight on this?

Comment: I would check your Xcode and iOS SDK version and upgrade them if necessary. Also check you have the last version for App Loader

Answer (score 0):

we had the same issue.
try to upload via xCode.
Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader.
It helped us))[image]